# google support for kotlin in android development

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As we now  Google announced  in  `2017` first-class support for Kotlin.

But what does it change? Is there more documentation for new features written in Kotlin language?
How does it affect Java?

My another question:
Are Kotlin written aps generally faster?(on Android device)

EDIT: Guys I though this question is properly asked.. Don't vote me down

Answer (score 1):

**Java Issues Addressed by Kotlin**

**NullSafety** — The Billion Dollar Mistake is the name given to the danger of null references in code. Kotlin’s type system is aimed at eliminating the danger of these null references. This has been one of the most common pitfalls in Java — and many other programming languages as well.
No more Raw Types — Kotlin is designed with Java interoperability in mind. So now, existing Java code can be called from Kotlin in an effective way. This allows the calling of Java code from Kotlin. Alternatively, Kotlin code can be used in Java rather smoothly.

**Invariant Arrays** — The basic types used in Kotlin are Numbers, Arrays, Characters, and Strings. Unlike Java, the arrays in this programming language are invariant, meaning that Kotlin does not let a user assign an Array to an Array. This prevents a possible Run time Failure, which is one of the issues faced in Java.
Function Types — In Kotlin, a lambda expression or an anonymous function can access the variables declared in the outer scope. That is opposed to Java’s SAM-conversions — Kotlin has proper function types.
Use-site Variance — Wildcard Types are one of the trickiest parts of Java’s Type System. This issue does not occur in Kotlin — as it does not have any Wildcard Types, just Type Projections and declaration-site variances.

**Exceptions** — Kotlin does not have any checked exceptions, as all exception classes in this language are the descendants of the class Throwable. And every exception has a message, stack trace, and an optional cause.
Why Choose Kotlin
Smart Casts
Working with the mixed types requires knowing the type of an object at the Run time in order to safely cast the object to the desired type — and, further, to call methods or access properties on it. For class casting in Java, we first check the type of the variable using the ‘instance of’ operator and then cast it to the target type.
Whereas in Kotlin, when we perform an ‘!is’ or ‘is’ check on a variable, the compiler tracks this information and will automatically cast the variable to the target type where is the ‘!is’ or ‘is’ check is true in the scope.

**Singletons**
Once in a while, a user needs to create an object of a slight modification of some class but without explicitly declaring a new subclass for it. Java handles this case with anonymous inner classes, but Kotlin generalizes the same concept by using object expressions and declarations. Just like the anonymous inner classes in Java, the code in object expressions can access variables from the enclosing scope. But in Kotlin, this is not restricted to final variables like in Java.

**Data Classes**
The whole purpose of creating classes is to hold data and in some classes — standard functionality with utility functions can be mechanically derived from that data. This is known as a Data Class in Kotlin. These classes generally contain some old boilerplate code in the form of toString(), hashcode(), equals(), setters, and getters.
Basically, Kotlin’s Data Classes are like regular classes but with some additional functionality.

*NOTE: There are more things that have in Kotlin which help developers to write faster, consize and clean code*

Comment: But why Kotlin is chosen as leading language for Android? Because of solving these issues?

Comment: Because as on survey most 90% android devs likes it and kotlin has support for java also but java has no support for kotlin

Comment: What do you say? Java has support for Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Comment: I mean to say that writing java support for kotlin we have to do extra bro